# How to fix "Path to chaincode does not exist" while installing chaincode on a peer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm trying to install chaincode written in typescript on a peer in a network with a single peer, couch DB, fabric CA and an orderer in solo mode. On running the script typescript is compiled to javascript successfully.

A later error message appears

> Error: error getting chaincode code miqlavecc: path to chaincode does
>   not exist: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode

[image: Error message while chaincode install]
I used this script file, deploycontract.sh:

```
CC_SRC_LANGUAGE = "typescript"
CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE=node # chaincode runtime language is node.js
    CC_SRC_PATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode #/fabcar/typescript
    echo Compiling TypeScript code into JavaScript ...
    pushd ../SmartContract/typescript/
    npm install
    npm run build
    popd
    echo Finished compiling TypeScript code into JavaScript

CONFIG_ROOT=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
ORG1_MSPCONFIGPATH=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/suja.miqlave.com/users/Admin@suja.miqlave.com/msp
ORG1_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/suja.miqlave.com/peers/peer0.suja.miqlave.com/tls/ca.crt
ORDERER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/miqlave.com/orderers/orderer.miqlave.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.miqlave.com-cert.pem

echo "Installing smart contract on peer0.suja.miqlave.com"
docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=SujaMSP \
  -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.suja.miqlave.com:7051 \
  -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${ORG1_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
  peer0.suja.miqlave.com \
  peer chaincode install \
    -n miqlavecc \
    -v 1.0 \
    -p "$CC_SRC_PATH" \
    -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE"
```

docker- compose.yaml:

```
version: "2"

networks:
  miqlave:

services:
  ca.miqlave.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.miqlave.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.suja.miqlave.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/7173c628839f14e9b1e4dbf6f73e60798c8fcf4a38cf9a6453080b0363d6a0cc_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/suja.miqlave.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.miqlave.com
    networks:
      - miqlave

  orderer.miqlave.com:
    container_name: orderer.miqlave.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
      - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/miqlave.com/orderers/orderer.miqlave.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/suja.miqlave.com/peers/peer0.suja.miqlave.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1
    networks:
      - miqlave

  peer0.suja.miqlave.com:
    container_name: peer0.suja.miqlave.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.suja.miqlave.com
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=SujaMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.suja.miqlave.com:7051 
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_miqlave
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/suja.miqlave.com/peers/peer0.suja.miqlave.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/suja.miqlave.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
      - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
      # - ./SmartContract:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
    depends_on:
      - orderer.miqlave.com
      - couchdb
    networks:
      - miqlave

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - miqlave

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.suja.miqlave.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=SujaMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/suja.miqlave.com/users/Admin@suja.miqlave.com/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
      - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    networks:
      - miqlave
```

Answer (score 2):

@Ravi

You have to mention full path for chaincode volume & remove src and start mentioning from github.com/

Update at volume as below

```
volumes:
  - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode/fabcar/typescript
```

and the CC_SRC_PATH as follows

`CC_SRC_PATH=github.com/chaincode/fabcar/typescript`

Comment: `volumes:
- ./../SmartContract/typescript/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/  
CC_SRC_PATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/dist`

This path worked for me. I was pointing to a different folder in the chaincode installation command  instead of pointing the variable to the path shared in volumes.